# Как сделать так, что каждому input number соответствовал свой input checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, input, checkbox

При увеличении значения input number выделяются все checkbox'ы, Как сделать так, что каждому "number" соответствовал свой "checkbox"? Поскажите пожалуйста новичку.

html

```
<div class="dance-type">
<div class="wrap-exact">
    Ballroom Standard
</div>
<div class="wrap-exact-check">
    <div class="check-item">
        <div class="check-item-wr">
            <input type="checkbox" id="dancetype1" name="dancetype1" value="Slow Waltz">
            <span>Slow Waltz </span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="quantity1" name="quantity1" placeholder="0" step="1" min="1" max="20">
        
    </div>

    <div class="check-item">
        <div class="check-item-wr">
            <input type="checkbox" id="dancetype2" name="dancetype2" value="Tango">
            <span>Tango</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="quantity2" name="quantity2" placeholder="0" step="1" min="1" max="20">
    </div>

    <div class="check-item">
        <div class="check-item-wr">
            <input type="checkbox" id="dancetype3" name="dancetype3" value="Venice Waltz">
            <span>Venice Waltz</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="quantity3" name="quantity3" placeholder="0" step="1" min="1" max="20">          
    </div>
    
    <div class="check-item">
        <div class="check-item-wr">
            <input type="checkbox" id="dancetype4" name="dancetype4" value="Foxtrot">
            <span>Foxtrot</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="quantity4" name="quantity4" placeholder="0" step="1" min="1" max="20">
    </div>
    
    <div class="check-item">
        <div class="check-item-wr">
            <input type="checkbox" id="dancetype5" name="dancetype5" value="Quickstep">
            <span>Quickstep</span>
        </div>
        <input type="number" id="quantity5" name="quantity5" placeholder="0" step="1" min="1" max="20"> 
    </div>
    

</div>
```

[image: общий вид части формы]
[image: когда нажимаю на input number, чекаются все все чекбоксы]

jquery (мои попытки сделать это на jquery)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check-item input[type="number"]').each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            var danceCount = $(this).val();
            console.log(danceCount);
        
            if( danceCount > 0 ) {
               $('.check-item input:checkbox').each(function() {
                   $('.check-item input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
               });
               
            } else {
               $('.check-item input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оборачиваем input и checkbox в один div и через jquery меняем состояние через siblings (соседние элементы)
UPD: Добавлен функционал снятия чекбокса при обнулении инпута

```js
  $('input[type="number"]').change(function(){
     $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
     let thisval = $(this).val();
     
     if (thisval == 0){
        $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="number" min="0">
<input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло) Очень благодарен Вам. 
Может вы еще подскажите, как в таком случае, сделать еще обратное, если в input number value станет 0. Как снять checked c чекбокса?

Comment: Изменил свой ответ. Если ответ вам помог, просьба пометить его как решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за помощь.